# How to spread data in ngx-datatable?

Tags: html, json, angular5, ngx-datatable

```
[
  {
    "id": "1231",
    "hero": "xys",
    "lastAddedDate": "2019-01-16",
    "movieDetails": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "movie": "xasdas",
        "director": "jdnka",
        "release date": "2019-01-19 18:33:51.894"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "movie": "zgh",
        "director": "Approved",
        "release date": "2019-01-19 18:33:51.894"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "123",
    "hero": "xysz",
    "lastAddedDate": "2019-01-16",
    "movieDetails": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "movie": "asdxasdasasd",
        "director": "asdfsjdnka",
        "release date": "2019-01-19 18:33:51.894"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "movie": "zygtas",
        "director": "owq",
        "release date": "2019-01-19 18:33:51.894"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

In this JSON, I want to spread all the data using `ngxDatatable` in the form of a table. Here, I'm facing with `movieDetails` array. when i try to populate `movieDetails` in table it is giving undefined.

**Here is the format of my table**

`Id` | `Hero` | `LastAddedDate` | `Movie1` | `Movie1Director` | `Movie1ReleaseDate` | `Movie2` | `Movie2Director` | `movie2ReleaseDate`

`|` - Column Seperator

Comment: In your JSON `movieDetails` is an array, you have to transform the data structure based on how you want to present them in UI. It seems you are treating them like objects here.

Comment: actually i want to extract all movies from that array and present in table. do you have any idea how to do that?